# Telerik MVC Chart: How to change databinding mode at client side using javascript?

Tags: telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik MVC barchart that uses serverside binding during startup for performance purpose. Afer the page is loaded. I want to change the databinding to AJAX, so the chart can update itself responding to other events. Can the databinding mode be updated using javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the values you want to initially load to the Chart constructor and also define an ajax binding and select method. After that once the page is loaded you can refresh the Chart with the following code

```
<code>
   $('#chartID').data().tChart.rebind()
</code>
```

Comment: I tried that. it worked. But the chart was drawn twice. First, when the vaulues passed to the chart. Then immediately, the AJAX call was invoked. Is there anyway to prevent the first AJAX call?

Comment: Yes you can declare a global variable which indicates if the first ajax request is prevented. Add the handler to the OnDataBinding event and if it is the first request use e.preventDefault() to prevent the chart from performing the first ajax request